# How to display data in jtree

Tags: java

i am trying to fetch data from database and display in jtree. i facing trouble ResultSet show the last value data` below my code

```
rs1=DB.Select("SELECT AcCode from tblCoa order by AcCode");

while(rs1.next()){
    DefaultMutableTreeNode Catagory=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rs1.getString("AcCode"));
    DefaultMutableTreeNode Catagories=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rs1.getString("AcCode"));
    DefaultMutableTreeNode Catagories2=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rs1.getString("AcCode"));
    DefaultMutableTreeNode Catagories3=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rs1.getString("AcCode"));
    DefaultMutableTreeNode Catagories4=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rs1.getString("AcCode"));
    Catagory.add(Catagories);
    Catagories.add(Catagories2);
    Catagories.add(Catagories3);
    Catagories.add(Catagories4);
    DefaultTreeModel dtm=new DefaultTreeModel(Catagory);
    this.jTree1.setModel( dtm);
}
```

Comment: could you put the all code inside a code block and describe what is the problem with your output?

Comment: private void FillData() throws SQLException{       
  ResultSet rs1=null;
  rs1=DB.Select("SELECT AcCode from tblCoa order by AcCode");
  while(rs1.next()){ DefaultMutableTreeNode Catagory=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rs1.getString("AcCode")); DefaultMutableTreeNode Catagories=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rs1.getString("AcCode"));

Comment: DefaultMutableTreeNode Catagories2=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rs1.getString("AcCode"));
 DefaultMutableTreeNode Catagories3=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rs1.getString("AcCode"));
 DefaultMutableTreeNode Catagories4=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rs1.getString("AcCode"));
Catagory.add(Catagories);
 Catagories.add(Catagories2);
  Catagories.add(Catagories3); Catagories.add(Catagories4);DefaultTreeModel dtm=newDefaultTreeModel(Catagory);
this.jTree1.setModel( dtm);}

Comment: @wasif please look at my edit to see how to format code. Comments are horrible for code blocks

Comment: The problem i am facing is retrieving the whole result set. i am just getting the last value in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

```
  DefaultMutableTreeNode Catagory = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();


  while(rs1.next()){
       Catagory.add(rs1.getString("AcCode")); 
  }
            DefaultTreeModel dtm=new DefaultTreeModel(Catagory);
            this.jTree1.setModel( dtm);
```

you initiate your variables inside the while loop . which will reset the previous data at each loop.and you have sevral `DefaultMutableTreeNode` variables which will store the same `rs1.getString("AcCode")` . i dont see a reason why. made some changes to the code try it now.

Comment: The problem i am facing is retrieving the whole result set. i am just getting the last value in the result set.

Comment: made some changes try it now.

Comment: i change it but i am just getting the last value in resultSet not whole resultSet

Comment: it gives error string can not be converted in MutableTreeNode